# How to achieve ingestion time?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I found the distinction between different notions of time in the Apache Flink documentation in [Event Time / Processing Time / Ingestion Time](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.4/dev/event_time.html#event-time--processing-time--ingestion-time).

> **Event time** is the time that each individual event occurred on its producing device.

And that's what datasets come with and so is available in Spark Structured Streaming out of the box.

> **Processing time** refers to the system time of the machine that is executing the respective operation.
>
> **Ingestion time** is the time that events enter Flink.

The two processing time and ingestion time are of my concern. I think I know how to achieve processing time, but am not sure about ingestion time (or perhaps I'm wrong and it's the opposite).

How to achieve ingestion time in Spark Structured Streaming 2.2 and later?

Comment: It's a good question to mailing list, Tathagata Das and Michael Armbrust are very helpful :)

Comment: I believe when we read the input stream we can specify this using .option("includeTimestamp", true).https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/39e2bad6a866d27c3ca594d15e574a1da3ee84cc/examples/src/main/python/sql/streaming/structured_network_wordcount_windowed.py

Comment: @AkhilanandBenkalVenkanna That's the option that I think is only available for socket streaming data source. Does this mean that different data sources use different ways to give the event time? It looks so.